# how to track last three clicked ID's in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery, i want to get the list of last `div ID's` minimum last three iD's.

my need is when user clicks on cancel button then i want to move user to last 2nd clicked div.

Comment: You should know how to write a good or at least satisfactory SO question by now. Being new to something is no excuse not to at least make an attempt at solving the problem. Show what you've tried, and explain exactly where your attempt went wrong

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var clicks = [];
$("div[id^=test]").on('click',function() {
    clicks.push(this.id);
});
$("button").on('click',function() {
    console.log(clicks.pop())
});
```

This uses a array to store all the clicks and the show & removes the last one on button click.

To read about [**.push()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and [**.pop()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9JjBQ/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Make an "history" array that push the id everytime the div is clicked :

```
var history = [];
$('div').click(function(){
    history.unshift(this.id);
})
```

And on cancel click:

```
$('button.cancel').click(function(){
    history.shift();
})
```

Comment: how to print this ids?

Comment: `history[0]` will always get the lastest added id. Using `history.shift()` will delete the first cell of history.

Answer (score 0):

To save previous clicks you'll want to store clicks in an array as follows:

```
clicks = [];
$(function () {
    $("div").on("click", function (e) {
        // The following is what you wanted, but the uncommented code is better (as it saves future DOM lookups)
        // clicks.shift($(this).attr("id"));
        clicks.shift(this);
        // If you want to use jQuery on the objects, you'll need to call jQuery on them ex: $(this)

        // If you do want to remove previous elements, uncomment the following code
        // if(clicks.length > 3){
        //  clicks.pop();
        // }
    });
});
```

Each time a click occurs, the object that was clicked on will be stored in the array (`clicks.push(this)`). Later you can reference the array. `clicks[0]` will have the most recent click, `clicks[1]` the next most recent, and so on.

So, to do what you described, you would make a function along the lines of:

```
$(function () {
    $("#cancel").on("click", function (e) {
        $(clicks[1]).yourMethods();
    });
});
```